# string to multi set haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples, multiset

Convert string to multi set as the example below:

"bacaba" --> [(b,2),(a,3),(c,1)]

```
type MSet a = [(a,Int)]

convert :: Eq a => [a] -> MSet
```

what is wrong with my code and what is the better way to do it? ty

```
convert :: Eq a => [a] -> MSet a
convert [] = []
convert (x:xs) = ((x,1+count x xs) : converte xs) 
  where count x [] = 0
        count x (y:ys) = if (x == y) then 1 + count x ys else count x ys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the better way to do it?

Your code performs `O(n^2)`; If the type is an instance of `Ord` type class (as in your example), using [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) you may get an `O(n log n)` performance:

```
import Data.Map (toList, fromListWith)

convert :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
convert xs = toList . fromListWith (+) . zip xs $ repeat 1
```

This would result in the right counts but the list would be sorted by the keys:

```
\> convert "bacaba"
[('a',3),('b',2),('c',1)]
```

If you need to preserve the order, then

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Map (delete, fromListWith)

convert :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
convert xs = foldr go (const []) xs . fromListWith (+) . zip xs $ repeat 1
    where
    go x f cnt = case M.lookup x cnt of
        Just i  -> (x, i): f (x `delete` cnt)
        Nothing -> f cnt
```

which would output:

```
\> convert "bacaba"
[('b',2),('a',3),('c',1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

The problem is with your recursive call to the `convert` function. Since you have already computed the number of characters for a particular character, you don't need to calculate them again. Just use a `filter` function to remove that character out while calling to `convert`:

```
convert :: Eq a => [a] -> MSet a
convert [] = []
convert (x:xs) = (x,1+count x xs) : convert (filter (\y -> y /= x) xs)
  where count x [] = 0
        count x (y:ys) = if (x == y) then 1 + count x ys else count x ys
```

Or written more concisely:

```
convert :: Eq a => [a] -> MSet a
convert [] = []
convert (x:xs) = (x,1+count x xs) : convert (filter (/= x) xs)
  where count x [] = 0
        count x (y:ys) = if (x == y) then 1 + count x ys else count x ys
```

Demo in ghci:

```
ghci| > convert "bacaba"
[('b',2),('a',3),('c',1)]
```